# java: convert object to list

Tags: java, list, tree

I have the following classes:

```
public class UnidadOrganicaArbol {

protected long codigo;
@XmlElement(required = true)
protected String denominacion;
protected boolean tieneOficinaRegistro;
protected int prelacion;
@XmlElement(required = true)
protected UnidadesOrganicasArbol subunidades;

/*getters and setters*/
}
```

and also have

```
public class UnidadesOrganicasArbol
extends ListadoBase
{

protected List<UnidadOrganicaArbol> unidadOrganicaArbol;


public List<UnidadOrganicaArbol> getUnidadOrganicaArbol() {
    if (unidadOrganicaArbol == null) {
        unidadOrganicaArbol = new ArrayList<UnidadOrganicaArbol>();
    }
    return this.unidadOrganicaArbol;
}
```

As you can see, `UnidadOrganicaArbol` class hass an attribute `subunidades` which is an `UnidadesOrganicasArbol` class, which has a `List<UnidadOrganicaArbol>` attribute.

So, I have a `UnidadOrganicaArbol` class that contains a `List<UnidadOrganicaArbol>` attribute.

Let´s say that I have:

[image]

do you know any general algorithm to convert uoa1 (or any other UnidadOrganicaArbol object) and its children into a list where I can keep their ids and id parents of the children?

I have tried several ways but no success. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So your SubUnidades may also contain lists of further Unidades? On first glance, this looks like a problem that may be solved by applying the composite pattern (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern)

Comment: You have your list of `UnidadOrganicaArbol` in `UnidadesOrganicasArbol` Its too confuse with names try to provide generic names

Comment: What have you tried? It's a simple recursive function.

Comment: That's the funnier algorithm to write at your level so you should at least try. Also, A [mcve] with simple name and with less attribute would be simpler (I have the class `Node` with a `List<Node>` and a `String name`. How to iterate it).

Comment: @AxelH, I don´t have how to iterate it. That is what I am asking.

Comment: @daniu, If it is simple for you, please provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public List<UnidadOrganicaArbol> collectToList(UnidadOrganicaArbol arbol) {
    List<UnidadOrganicaArbol> result = new ArrayList<>();
    result.add(arbol);
    UnidadesOrganicasArbol children = arbol.getUnidadesOrganicasArbol();
    if (children != null) {
        for (UnidadOrganicaArbol child : children.getUnidadOrganicaArbol()) {
            result.addAll(collectToList(child));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

will yield you the list [\, 7, 3, 6, 4, 5, 1, 2] for the above picture.